# multiple choices in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have tried IIF, IF Else and Case none seem to work. If there is a value in @ShippedDate then query on that value alone or query on the other values.

```
 WHERE 
    (CASE WHEN @ShippedDate  != NULL THEN date_shipped = @ShippedDate 
     ELSE   
    [order].order_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND program_types.id IN ( @ProgTypes )
    AND employee.id IN (@RepNames)
    END
    ORDER BY OrderID
```

Comment: Case is an expression, it is used to return the value of a column. You can't use like this to conditionally swap out other predicates. And nothing will ever equal NULL, just as nothing will even not equal NULL.

Comment: `id IN ( @ProgTypes )`? Is that even possible in SQL Server? Is `@ProgTypes` some kind of array variable?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sure it is possible as long it contains only a single value. ;) But I suspect they are not doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure something like this is what you are looking for. However, I don't think you are actually done here. I notice you are using IN with scalar values. If those values contain a comma separated list this will still not work.

```
WHERE 
(
    date_shipped = @ShippedDate --This will not be true if @ShippedDate is null
    OR
    (
        @ShippedDate is null
        AND
        [order].order_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    )
)
AND program_types.id IN ( @ProgTypes )
AND employee.id IN (@RepNames)
ORDER BY OrderID
```

Comment: If I add a date I get all the records If I add null I no records.  The logic Im looking for is if there is a value I get records with that value If null then it gives the rest of the where. This doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Oops....I had a NOT null in the second part which was backwards. And keep in mind that you didn't provide much in the way of details so everybody here is guessing.

Comment: It worked, I'm such an idiot I had date_shipped as ship_date. TY for the help it works as expected. gj.

Comment: If this works you should consider marking this is the answer.